# What is $HC_0(\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy))$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology

Does anybody know how to compute $HC_0(\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy))$? Here $HC_0(-)$ is the zeroth cyclic homology group.

I'm curious since $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]/(xy)$ can be viewed as the union of affine lines.